# ASP.NET MVC 3 C# MySQL, use ON DELETE CASCADE feature or DELETE rows in CONTROLER?

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, cascade, sql-delete

I need an opinion from experienced people,

mySQL situation, 2 tables, one to many relation:

I have one table A with A_id(PK) and A_name, and one table B with B_id(PK) and B_foto and A_id(FK to table A(A_id).

If I put the FK ON DELETE CASCADE option and then I delete a ROW in table A, all rows in table B that are refered to A_id will be deleted, right? OK.

But if the B_foto is a string with the path to some file image and i want to delete the file too, it's better to me to NOT USE the ON DELETE CASCADE option and check manualy in the Controler(C#) if table B has some references to A and delete the rows manualy because i want to delete de files too..

If I use the ON DELETE CASCADE option, i will loose the reference to the files that i want to delete.. right?

Maybe if i keep the ON DELETE CASCADE option, and first check table B for the references to table A only to delete the files, then I delete the ROW in table A and it(mySQL) deletes de ROWS in table B..

Hope you can elucidate me on that question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The later of the choice seems a more reliable solution, as you do not need to commit the changes to the database unless the deletion is a success.

Although there is no single way to go about this, using the cascade delete is still a valid option, you just need to look at the execution order ;) Iterate through the files, process for deletion, on success delete the parent row.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer, maybe you can vote my question, it will help other people with same doubt..

I think that i will iterate de child table to delete de files, then i delete the parent table row and (with on delete cascade) it deletes de childs rows that i already deleted the corresponding files..